# C# -- C++ Intellisense textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to make a textbox control display C++ intelisense just like it would in Visual Studios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835682/how-does-intellisense-work-in-visual-studio) and this ['DIY Intellisense' Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/diy-intellisense.aspx) from the top answer.  That's in C#, but the same set of controls is accessable through C++.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about embedding a control in your own app.  You could look at [Actipro SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/wpf/syntaxeditor/default.aspx).  It will color the C++ right out of the box.  If you want intelliprompt/sense you will have supply a parser.  They have stuff to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I gather you are talking about an AutoComplete popup, not actual intellisense.

[image: (Auto-complete image)]

To do this, set the [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.aspx) of the textbox to Suggest (or SuggestAppend) and choose the appropriate [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletesource.aspx)

```
combDogBreeds.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
combDogBreeds.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

string[] validDogBreeds = new[] {"Bull Mastiff", "Bulldog", "Golden Retriever"};
combDogBreeds.Items.AddRange(validDogBreeds);
```

Or, in the designer:

[image: (Auto Complete in designer)]