# Please suggest a nice link for learning about radix tree data-structure !

Tags: algorithm

I'm totally new to radix tree datastructure, can someone share a link as reference for learning about radix tree for beginners ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Answer (score 1):

Well, google "radix tree" and go "I feel lucky" and you will end up on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)
Start from there, and return here with your code if something would go astray ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794601/prefix-search-in-a-radix-tree-patricia-trie) question on SO that has some links to it, and then the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) also seems to have some data and links.